# From FileMaker Pro 10 to FileMaker Server 14: Unable to edit some of the old records

Tags: database, debugging

We have recently upgraded our registry from a PC based FileMaker Pro 10 to FileMaker Server 14. The upgrade process was doen without any specific problems.
However, we have realized that we are unable to edit most of the older records, but now all of them. We need to use the Revert field command to proceed when we are unable to do the changes we want. Newer records can be changed without problems. Can someone give a us a hint for a solution?